# Question about limit points.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, sequences-and-series

I just have a short (most likely trivial) question regarding this assignment:

> Let $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a (real) subsequence. Let $A \subset\mathbb{R}$ be the set of limit points in $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and $B \subset\mathbb{R}$ the set of limit points in $M = \{x_n\,|\,n\in\mathbb{N}\}$.
>
> (Prove that $B \subset A$ and show that there is a sequence so that $A$ is an infinite set an $B = \varnothing$.)

I am just wondering what exactly the difference is between the set of limit points of a sequence (here: $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$) and set of limit points of a set (here: $M = \{x_n\,|\,n\in\mathbb{N}\}$).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider the sequence $(x_n)=1,3,1/2,3,1/4,3,1/8,3,\dots$. Then $3$ is a limit point of a subsequence of our sequence. But the **set** of points of the form $x_n$ is $\{3,1,1/2,1/4,\dots\}$ and does not have $3$ as a limit point.

Comment: Try $(x_n)=\{0,0,1,0,1,2,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,4,\dots,0,1,2,\dots,k,\dots\}$

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand now. @doppz Obviously, your sequence also fulfills the requirements to be the sequence asked for in my assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Consider the sequence $(x_n)=1,3,1/2,3,1/4,3,1/8,3,….$ Then 3 is a limit point of a subsequence of our sequence. But the set of points of the form $x_n$ is ${3,1,1/2,1/4,…}$ and does not have 3 as a limit point."